# What is this connector in my tractor?

Tags: connector, identification

[image]

I have lots of these connectors in my MT765.  The dealer only sells full harnesses with this as part of it.  I want to buy a bunch that I can crimp myself (of both male and female parts).  How can I identify the connector so that I can find some?

Comment: Those connectors are likely totally custom to your tractor manufacturer. I think you should look at all the 4-way connectors that you claim are hanging on your tractor. There is a good possibility that that many of they may be keyed differently. The picture gives the distinct impression that there are a good number of keying possibilities based upon where the wide slots are placed on what is the "bottom" in the picture.

Comment: Don't miss [mechanics.SE], maybe ask a moderator to migrate this question over to the mechanics stack.

Comment: Kyler, if you have not done it, just ask the dealer.  Tell him you are interested in buying only the connectors, and if he can't get them for you, then ask him for the manufacturer's address and phone number.